# Oracle Data Pump Export ignores table

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I'm running the following command to export the schema and data of all the tables/views of schema `dbname`:

```
expdp dbname/pwd DIRECTORY=backups DUMPFILE=data-2019-7-10.dmp 
      LOGFILE=export.log SCHEMAS=dbname
```

Problem is that one of the tables is called `ACTIVITY_LOG` and it is ignored by the export (I don't see the table in the output list). What could be the reason?

**UPDATE**

I can see the ACTIVITY_LOG table in SQL developer:

[image]

But in the dump log it's not in the list:

```
;;; 
Export: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Jul 10 10:26:06 2019
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Starting "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  BK0001PRODCONFIG/******** DIRECTORY=backups DUMPFILE=config-data-2019-7-10.dmp LOGFILE=config_export.log SCHEMAS=BK0001PRODCONFIG 
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/IDENTITY_COLUMN
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/VIEW
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."FORMULA_FUNCTIONS"      87.08 KB    1139 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."BI_CHARTS"              43.60 KB       2 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."VALUE_ITEMS"            31.18 KB      21 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."TABLES"                 28.71 KB      14 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."EXPORTS"                27.45 KB       6 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."BI_MAPS"                23.57 KB       6 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."SYSTEM_LOG"                 0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."TABLE_COLUMNS"          18.25 KB      39 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."OLAP_QUERIES"           18.53 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."BI_SNAPSHOTS"           182.7 KB       3 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."FORMULAS"               16.82 KB       6 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."FILE_REST_PROPERTIES"   16.17 KB       8 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."VALUES2"                14.46 KB       3 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."USERS"                  13.77 KB       4 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."PALETTES"               13.07 KB       4 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."EXPORT_COLUMNS"         12.93 KB      52 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."STT_FEATURE_DATASETS"   12.56 KB      18 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."BI_CHART_COORDS"        12.19 KB       5 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."META_COLUMNS"           11.85 KB      87 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."SQL_QUERIES"            11.59 KB      15 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."QB_FILTERS"             11.64 KB       2 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."DS_VARS"                11.50 KB      22 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."DASH_ELEMENTS"          11.68 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."ADDITIONAL_DATA_COLUMNS"  11.24 KB      14 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."QUERY_BUILDERS"         10.60 KB       2 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."BI_CHART_COLUMNS"       10.62 KB      13 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."BI_MAP_ITEMS"           10.50 KB      28 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."VISUAL_VALUES"          10.18 KB      80 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."ADDITIONAL_DATA_TABLES"  9.625 KB       8 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."BI_CHART_ADV_OPTIONS"   8.656 KB      44 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."STT_LIABILITIES"        8.820 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."PERMISSIONS"            8.812 KB      42 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."USER_ROLE_PERMISSIONS"  9.007 KB     113 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."STT_ASSETS"             8.812 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."FILE_FIELD_PATHS"       8.617 KB      12 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."ANALYSIS"               8.460 KB       7 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."VISUAL_DSS"             8.593 KB      32 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."STT_FEATURES"           8.460 KB       3 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."STT_MODELS"             8.296 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."USER_ROLES"             8.046 KB       4 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."ADDITIONAL_DATA_GROUPS"  7.992 KB       5 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."QB_COLUMNS"             8.046 KB       8 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."META_TABLES"            7.960 KB       5 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."QB_TABLES"              7.523 KB       4 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."STT_ASSET_COLUMNS"      7.492 KB       3 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."STT_LIABILITY_COLUMNS"    7.5 KB       3 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."QB_LINKS"                 7.5 KB       2 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."EMAIL_SELECTION"        7.218 KB       7 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."SYSTEM_TASKS"           6.968 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."TAG_SELECTION"          6.703 KB       9 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."META_FOLDERS"           6.539 KB       5 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."STT_FEATURE_GROUPS"     6.531 KB       4 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."TAGS"                   6.437 KB      10 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."BI_CHART_OPTIONS"       6.539 KB       3 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."FOLDER_PROPERTIES"      6.414 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."BI_MAP_OPTIONS"         6.492 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."BI_MAP_ADV_OPTIONS"     6.085 KB      10 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."DASHBOARDS"             6.062 KB       2 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."EMAIL_ADDRESSES"        5.601 KB       3 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."META_IND_COL_NOTES"     5.585 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."META_IND_TABLE_NOTES"   5.585 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."EMAILS"                     0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."OLAP_DIMENSIONS"            0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."OLAP_LEVELS"                0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."REPORTS"                    0 KB       0 rows
Master table "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for BK0001PRODCONFIG.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
  D:\BACKUPS\DATA\CONFIG-DATA-2019-7-10.DMP
Job "BK0001PRODCONFIG"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Wed Jul 10 10:26:55 2019 elapsed 0 00:00:49
```

Comment: Are you sure it is actually a table in that schema; not a table in another schema, maybe with just a a synonym to make it easily queryable?

Comment: I created the table manually in SQL developer and it's in the schema when I click on "Tables"

Comment: Then are you sure you were actually connected to the same database (as well as schema)? If you log in from the same place you're trying to export, with `sqlplus dbname/pwd`, can you see the table in `user_tables`?

Comment: Yes, I can see the table in sqlplus

Comment: OK, interesting. If you just created the table, does it have any data yet; and if not was it created with deferred segment creation?

Comment: just created the table empty in SQL developer with some columns and all the defaults at the table level.